# Structure of a python project that is not a package

Tags: python, structure, project

If you search over the internet about python project structures, you will find some articles about python package structure. Based on it, What I want to know is if there is any kind of instructions for creating structure for python projects that isn't packages, that is, projects that the code is the end code it self?

For example, I created a package that handles some requests of some specific endpoints. This package will serve the main code that will handle the data fetched by this package. The main code is not a package, that is, it don't have classes and `__init__` files, because in this software layer, there will be no necessity of code reuse. Instead, the main code relate straight to the end it self.

Is there any instructions for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be good to see the structure itself instead of reading the description of it - it can help visualize the problem and answer properly to your case

> projects that isn't packages, that is, projects that the code is the end code it self

In general, I would say you should always structure your code! And by telling that, I mean exactly the work with the modules/packages. It is needed mostly to sperate the responsibilities and to introduce things that can be reused. It also gives the possibility to find things easier/faster instead of going through the unstructured tones of the code.

Of course, as I said, it is a general thought and as far as you are experienced you can experiment with the structure to find the best one for the project which you are working on. But without any structure, you won't survive in a bigger project (or the life will be harder than you want).

Comment: I don't really have a project structure because I didn't started to write the code. As I said, I wrote the package, but not the software that will use the package. I guess you are right about structures. The thing is that I am looking for some structure that will make my software more consistent and readable, the way I can change the code easily and consistently when it is running in production to garantee it's longevity.

Comment: I guess, maybe it's a good start to study some design patterns...

Comment: I could say go with the Clean Architecture everywhere but there is no one silver bullet for all the projects and this approach won't give you the result just because you use it   Getting familiar with the design patterns are also a good idea but I think you need to learn by doing - you can always move the code after a month when you decide that you didn't make the best choice. Other than that, with the exact example, I can tell more.

Comment: Right, I agree with you. I will start the main project and see what happends, instead trying to look for the best approach before doing anything. I need to get hands on it! Thanks for the advice!